# C# Excel Interop - Equivalent of Axis Type option

Tags: c#, excel, charts, interop

I've done a chart in interop c#.

I just need to change the Axis Type.

[image]

How can I do this ?

Thx.
Florence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem is :

```
m_XAxe.CategoryType = MSWord.XlCategoryType.xlTimeScale;
```

or

```
m_XAxe.CategoryType = MSWord.XlCategoryType.xlAutomaticScale;
```

or

```
m_XAxe.CategoryType = MSWord.XlCategoryType.xlCategoryScale;
```